# mysqlworkbench Error 1142: Create Command denied to user 'readonly'@'

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1142

I am trying to crate a table in MySQL workbench, but am running into this error.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CREATE command denied to user？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887364/create-command-denied-to-user)

Comment: i try his statement but then receive an error 1044

Comment: You are probably not allowed to grant any privs and your `readonly` user is really that by intention: read-only, not allowed to do changes in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Had to be given access by db admin

Comment: Stack Overflow flagged this answer automatically because it's short, but I think it does answer the question.